# Linq to select highest ID where the ID is alphanumeric

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of ID where the ID's start with MB (for members) or NM (for non members).

The ID would be like MB-101 or NM-108 etc...

I am trying to select the Highest ID starting with MB and then Add 1 and then save back to DB. Saving is easy but I am not sure how to query the highest Member or Nonmember ID and add one to it. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This is on your database I presume? The tag says entity-framework. If so, I suggest this is very inefficient design, as you SQL Server ids will auto increment and be nicely queryable. You'd have the MB or NM in another column. Perhaps you have a good reason though...

Comment: To clarify further - you'd need to do the querying you want *after* the SQL query part, so in-memory, in C#. That's why it's not efficient.

Comment: I agree this is probably not efficient but I inherited the System. There is an ID field this field basically gives them a unique membership ID like MB-103 .

Comment: Right - well you could normalize the database. But barring that, you will need to use .AsEnumerable() in your query, then use something like the code offered in the answer below by M Adeel Khalid to do the selection. I don't think there's anything in SQL to do it, so EF's Linq to SQL conversion won't be able to either. If the table is not huge - a few thousands at most - you should be OK doing the Linq querying in memory on an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "MB-101", "MB-102", "MB-103", "MB-104"};
var ids = list.Select(x =>Convert.ToInt32(x.Replace("MB-", "")));//convert all the number parts to integer
list[list.FindIndex(x => x == "MB-" + ids.Max().ToString())] = "MB-" + (ids.Max() + 1);//set the max number after adding one.
```

You can do the same with your Nonmember ID. It is tested code, it successfully addresses your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You missed the IDs starting with NM-. Easier and more efficient to use Substring to remove the first 3 chars.

Comment: Thanks for the help even more thanks for the self explanatory comments

Comment: This is my finished code:

    List<string> list = _applicationRepository.GetMemberIDs();
                    var ids = list.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Replace("NM-", "")));//convert all the number parts to integer
                    application.SLicenseNo = "NM-" + (ids.Max() + 1);//set the max number after adding one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the max id by splitting your list like below:

```
var ids = yourList.Where(x => x.ID.StartsWith("MB-")).Select(x => new { ID = x.ID.Split('-')[1] }).ToList();
var maxIdValue = ids.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ID)).ToList().Max();
```

If you want max id from both starting with MB- and NB- than you can remove above where condition. By this it will fetch max id from both MB- and NB-. Following will be query than:

```
var ids = yourList.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID.Split('-')[1] }).ToList();
var maxIdValue = ids.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ID)).ToList().Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
List<string> lststr = new List<string>() { "MB-101", "MB-103", "MB-102", "NM-108" };

var result = "MB-"+ lststr
            .Where(x=>x.Contains("MB"))
            .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"[^\d]", ""))
            .OrderByDescending(x=>x)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

it will return `MB-103` because it will first check if the string contains `MB` then it will replace everything with `""` other than digit and `OrderByDescending` it will order by Descending so that the highest value will be on top and at last `FirstOrDefault` will get the fist value

Answer (score 0):

You have to do **OrderByDescending** your list by replacing **MB** or **NM** with empty and get **FirstOrDefault** from ordered list. Please check below example.

CODE:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "MB-101", "MB-102", "MB-109", "MB-105", "NM-110"};
var maxMember = list.OrderByDescending(m=>Convert.ToInt16(m.Replace("MB-","").Replace("NM-",""))).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(maxMember.ToString());
```